# i want to convert this react js code and put it in angular component

Tags: reactjs, angular, migration, tesseract, tesseract.js

I want to implement real time video recognition that I found  in this react project and put it in my angular component

```
 import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
    import { createWorker } from 'tesseract.js';
    
    const worker = createWorker();
    
    // video config
    const vidWidth = window.innerWidth - 60; // can be controlled
    const vidHeight = 260; // can be controlled
    const vidOffsetTop = 240; // can be controlled
    const vidOffsetLeft = ((window.innerWidth) / 3) - (vidWidth / 2); // is centered, but if you want to change also can
    
    // indicator config
    const marginX = 40; // margin left and right, can be controlled
    const indWidth = vidWidth - marginX; // 100% width - margin, can be changed if you want
    const indHeight = 80; // can be controlled
    const indOffsetTop = vidOffsetTop + (vidHeight / 2) - (indHeight / 2); // is centered, if you want to change also can
    const indOffsetLeft = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (indWidth / 2); // is centered, if you want to change also can
    
    const App = ({ setCode, setScanning }) => {
        const myVideo = useRef();
        const myStream = useRef();
        const scannedCodes = useRef();
    
        useEffect(() => {
            if (myVideo && myVideo.current) {
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    video: { facingMode: "environment" },
                    audio: false
                })
                .then(stream => {
                    myVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
                    myVideo.current.play();
        
                    myStream.current = stream;
                    scannedCodes.current = {};
        
                    (async () => {
                        await worker.load();
                        await worker.loadLanguage("eng");
                        await worker.initialize("eng");
                        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
                    })()
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error(err);
                    // handle error here with popup
                })
            }
    
            return () => myStream && myStream.current && myStream.current.getTracks().forEach(x => x.stop());
            // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
        }, []);
    
        const tick = async () => {
            if (myVideo && myVideo.current && myVideo.current.readyState === myVideo.current.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA) {
                // canvas
                const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width = indWidth;
                canvas.height = indHeight;
    
                const image = myVideo.current;
                // source 
                const sx = (marginX / 2) / 2;
                const sy = vidHeight - indHeight;
                const sWidth = indWidth * 2;
                const sHeight = indHeight * 2;
                // destination
                const dx = 0;
                const dy = 0;
                const dWidth = indWidth;
                const dHeight = indHeight;
    
                canvas.getContext("2d")
                .drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
    
                // tesseract
                const { data: { text } } = await worker.recognize(canvas);
                const regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9]/gi;
                const scannedText = text && text.match(regex) && text.match(regex).filter(x => x).join("");
                console.log({text, scannedText});
                requestAnimationFrame(tick);
            }
        };
    
        return (
            <div>
                <video
                    ref={myVideo}
                    autoPlay
                    muted
                    playsInline
                    width={vidWidth}
                    height={vidHeight}
                    style={{
                        position: "absolute",
                        top: vidOffsetTop,
                        left: vidOffsetLeft,
                        zIndex: 2
                    }}
                ></video>
                <div
                    style={{
                        width: indWidth,
                        height: indHeight,
                        border: "1px red solid",
                        zIndex: 3,
                        position: "absolute",
                        top: indOffsetTop,
                        left: indOffsetLeft
                    }}
                ></div>
            </div>
        )
    };
    
    export default App;
```

Can someone tell me what steps I need to follow to convert the code into my angular component?

Do I need to copy the file jsx and change extension to tsx or to copy code and put it directly in my ts component, or how?